# Cannot Copy and Paste Files using CTRL+C and CTRL+V commands in Lubuntu File Manager

Tags: lubuntu

Starting from a few minutes ago, I cannot copy and paste files from some of my folders to the others. For example in this pic I wanted to copy a file from desktop and paste it in my home directory, but got this error instead.

[image: Error]

Sometimes after this error, my system randomly opens Visual Studio Code. I am completely clueless how this has happened and how to fix it.

I am using Lubuntu 18.10. (I ran `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` on my Ubuntu 18.10).

Edit: the output of `ls -al`. The file I'm having problem copying with shortcuts is "roole.jpg", I can copy the file using right click and choosing "Copy" and then going to the source destination and paste it via right click, but cannot use shortcuts.

```
total 60388
drwxr-xr-x 13 farhood farhood     4096 مارس  26 13:28  .
drwxr-xr-x 90 farhood farhood     4096 مارس  26 13:42  ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood    33007 اوت    1  2018 '1. Intro to Keras.ipynb'
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood    42716 اكتبر 22 10:28 'Algorithm (3).png'
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood   513079 مارس   9 00:14  andy.gif
drwx------  2 farhood farhood     4096 مارس  26 13:28  B_Nazanin
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood    26594 ژانوی 15 22:55  Concat.png
drwxr-xr-x  4 farhood farhood     4096 اوت    2  2018  DL
drwxrwxr-x  2 farhood farhood     4096 مارس  12 00:37  Grades_dup
drwx------  2 farhood farhood     4096 اوت    1  2018  img
drwxr-xr-x  2 farhood farhood     4096 اوت    1  2018  .ipynb_checkpoints
-rwxr-xr-x  1 farhood farhood 23615736 مارس  17  2017  iris-mini-0.3.8.AppImage
-rwxrwxrwx  1 farhood farhood      276 سپتام 14  2017 'Iris mini.desktop'
-rwxrwxrwx  1 farhood farhood   734204 دسامب 13  2017  Konkour.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 farhood farhood   647908 سپتام 30  2017  ME.png
drwxr-xr-x  2 farhood farhood     4096 اكتبر 17  2014  Nightmare
drwxr-xr-x  9 farhood farhood     4096 مارس   5  2014  Numix
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood   291359 مارس  10 12:00  PaperCertificate.pdf.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood    48649 فوریه 20 18:38  photo_۲۰۱۷-۰۴-۰۸_۱۶-۵۹-۱۶.jpg
drwxr-xr-x  2 farhood farhood     4096 مارس  22 10:29  __pycache__
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood      128 مارس  22 11:05  random_gen.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood  2694320 اوت    1  2018  raw_model.h5
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood   343491 فوریه 20 18:30  Representational_Learning_from_Persian.docx
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood   915350 فوریه 20 18:35  Representational_Learning_from_Persian.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood  1395611 مارس  26 12:18  roole.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood    46455 مارس  11 15:27  Rorschach.jpg
drwxrwxr-x  2 farhood farhood     4096 فوریه  1 12:55  Telegram
drwxrwxr-x  5 farhood farhood     4096 مارس  26 11:56  vazi
-rw-rw-r--  1 farhood farhood 30356838 مارس  16 22:55  video_2019-03-16_22-53-15.mp4
drwxrwxr-x  2 farhood farhood     4096 ژانوی 11  2018  VPNMakers
-rwxrw-r--  1 farhood farhood      268 فوریه 24  2018  xdm.desktop
-rwxrwxrwx  1 farhood farhood    26617 سپتام 16  2013  فرهود.JPG
```

Comment: You haven't said what release of Lubuntu you are using.  I'm using a recent release (using LXQt thus `pcmanfm-qt`) and had no issues using your listed copy & paste commands.  If you get the error on specific files, I'd be tempted to drop to terminal & check you have ownership of those files, that they are ordinary files - though you could use right-click-properties to explore using `pcmanfm-qt`  (If you were using Lubuntu 18.04 (LXDE) or earlier; you didn't state, so I tested with LXQt)

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, I had forgotten to mention it. I hadn't have any problems with my Lubuntu before today, I have had it for about a month now and had no problems with copying and pasting files.

Comment: I have never used visual studio code, so I ignored that info (i read it as `vim` in my mind).  The fact that it opens vscode is possibly a clue, and I'd check for unusual characters in the name (maybe spaces [acting as delimiters] in filenames, quotes or special characters that throw off the copy/paste). If it were my issue, I'd examine the filenames (copy & paste them into a dumb-editor list so you can look for non-displayable-chars, or if none are found, look for a pattern for clues).  This is an idea, `pcmanfm-qt` is open source, so you could even go looking at how it works. my 2c

Comment: @DKBose using  `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` I changed my Ubuntu to Lubuntu, although it's not the same as installing a clean Lubuntu.

Comment: @DKBose you're welcome! I have rebooted, logged out, even checked the shortcuts multiple times using `nano /.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @DKBose no they work fine, they even work copying other files from other folders. It's just that they cannot copy anything from desktop to paste in other locations. I can also copy from other locations and paste in the desktop. It's weird actually.

Comment: @DKBose I'm using the "Files"  software, not pcmanfm. Here is an image of its "About" option. https://pasteboard.co/I7c6hL5.png

Comment: @DKBose I have just tested pcmanfm-qt, and it has no such problem. It's only exclusive to Nautilus apparently.

Comment: Then just use pcmanfm-qt when you log into a Lubuntu session until someone can help you figure things out.